# Prove that there always exists a line and a point for the given curve satisfying the given condition.

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems, curves

Let a there be a second degree curve represented by,
$$S_1:ax²+2hxy+by²+2gx+2fy+c=0$$
Where atleast one of $a,b,h≠0$ and $a,b,c,h,g,f∈ℝ$

Prove that there always exists a point $S$ and line $L$, which which satisfies,
$$\frac{SP}{PM}=e$$

Where $P$ is any point on $S_1$ and $M$ is the foot of perpendicular from $P$ to $L$. And $e\geq0$ is a constant real number.

**My approach :**

I firstly tried making cases that if, $\Delta=0$ or $≠0$ for curve. So, for $\Delta=0$ curve represents a straight line as it can be factored in to linear expressions. But I can't figure it out for $\Delta≠0$. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please share your thoughts , your works upon the same question .

Comment: You'd better choose another name for point $S$, it's the same as the curve.

Comment: You know that conic sections have focus and directrix, don't you?

Comment: By the way: that property is false for a circle, unless you allow $L$ to be at infinity.

Comment: Yes $L$ doesn't have any limits, It could be imaginary (in case of imaginary lines on solving $S_1$), and ofcourse can be at infinity.

Comment: Yes, I know conics have directrix and focus but I haven't seen any proof regarding this in general.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_Definitions_of_Conic_Section

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833973/prove-that-the-directrix-focus-and-focus-focus-definitions-are-equivalent